# Open two editors with the same label

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, e4

I've recently developed a new RCP application with eclipse e4 and now I have run into a problem that whenever I want to open another editor which has the same label, that I cannot open it because I always check if there is already an open editor with the same label and then grant this editor focus in order to bring it on top of the part stack.
I use a part descriptor to dynamically open an editor whenever the user double-clicks on a tree element and then uses the tree elements name as label. Now it can happen that some tree elements have the same label ... 
Is there any other way in eclipse e4 I can check if an editor is already open, besides comparing the label of all open editors with the label of the editor I want to open?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the objects being edited different? Can you compare the objects rather than the label?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes the objects being edited are different, but I couldn't figure out how to access this objects ... I iterate over all open MParts in the editor stack, but how to access the objects being edited by the respective MPart?

Comment: MPart.getObject() gives you your editor class, or store something in the MPart transient data.

Answer (score 0):

The default way is assigning an input uri while creating an editor (InputPart in e4)

```
MInputPart inputPart = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createInputPart();
inputPart.setInputURI("someInputUri");
```

And then you can call:

```
Collection<MInputPart> inputParts = partService.getInputParts("someInputUri");
```

Where *partService* is an instance of *EPartService*. You can manage a group of input parts using this approach.

Comment: `MInputPart` is now deprecated